# How do I combine two arrays in bash, by summing like-indices?

Tags: bash

Say I have two arrays (or an array or arrays!) in bash like so

```
a=(1 0 1)
b=(0,1,1)
```

how do I combine them into:

```
c=(1 1 2)
```

Where each element is added together to make c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, array definitions in `bash` don't take `,` between the array elements, they are just defined simply as

```
a=(1 0 1)
b=(0 1 1)
```

To generate the new array with the sum of the elements in the same indices, iterate over either of the array indices (assuming same array length in both cases) do

```
for idx in "${!a[@]}"; do 
    c[idx]=$(( a[idx] + b[idx] ))
done
```

Instead of iterating over the indices with `${!a[@]}`, one could also use a traditional C-style for loop iterating up to the array length

```
for (( idx=0; idx < ${#a[@]}; idx++ )); do
```

Finally, to print the result in the new array you can do something like

```
printf '%s\n' "${c[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
a=(1,0,1)
b=(0,1,1)
a1=(`echo $a | tr ',' ' '`)
b1=(`echo $b | tr ',' ' '`)
for i in `seq 0 1 ${#a1[@]}`
do
        c1[$i]=`expr ${a1[$i]} + ${b1[$i]}`
done
c=(`echo ${c1[@]} | tr ' ' ','`)
```